# Is it true that at times it may be more beneficial NOT to call mysqli_result::free, mysqli_result::close, mysqli_result::free_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it true that at times it may be more beneficial NOT to call `mysqli_result::free`, `mysqli_result::close`, `mysqli_result::free_result` especially when the page itself is short and since php will automatically free the resources once the page itself has finished processing?

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Just a reminder (there's a reason why I put it as a comment rather than an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you do it or PHP does that for you, I don't see a difference, you wont gain anything. But it is bad to get a habit of omitting free, and close functions just because it is done for you automatically. One day you might forget to do it inside a loop where it matters.

Comment: Excuse me, i really didnt know what you mean with : "You wont gain anything" here. Can you please ellaborate that, since i believe it did. Freeing memmory immediately, after did some sequence queries is alot better rather than leave all queries running simmultaneously in a single HTTP request and let PHP done for you automaticly in the end of that request, especially when you are in the middle of tunning your v2 app and every milisecond is a gold.

Comment: @toopay: if you have single query in a single PHP file which ends right after you free the query and close the connection, well it doesn't really matter if you don't explicitly state it should close it, it is guaranteed to be closed at the end of the script which happens to be the next line. But as I said you should not make it a habit as it is a bad practice and bad habits don't go well with programming.

Comment: Off course, if it was a single query, thats nothing to do with freeing memory. We both aggred its bad habbit. But what i want from you, is a clarification of your statement : "You wont gain anything". Because if i have 10000 records of cities and i did several queries in a single HTTP request, even if it was just ten or thirty milisecond, i found it did "something". 15-20% of performance improvement, is something.

Comment: @toopay: question was about a short PHP and by saying you wont gain anything I imply: "You wont gain anything by not freeing memory, since it will be freed anyway".

Answer (score 0):

I will said : FALSE. Especially if you do alot of simple queries, having nested queries everywhere in your database abstraction and in the same time want a very efficient (in performance terms) apps. Do some benchmarking, and its result will speak the truth.